# class based templateview context is not rendering

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a template view that is supposed to take in a user submitted search. I planning to use the get method to do a query in the get_context_data so that I can show some results on the HTML. Unfortunately, my get_context_data does not work while the get method and dispatch in my templateview works fine. The get_context_data does not run at all when the user submits the search.

```
class PollSearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'polls/polls_search.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.request.session["search"] = request.GET.get("search")
        return render(request, 'polls/polls_search.html')

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dispatch = super(PollSearchView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        #exit if no search
        if self.request.GET.get("search") == None:
            pass
            return redirect('/')
        return dispatch

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PollSearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        search = self.request.session.get("search")
        context["test"] = search
        return context
```

I have another class that is redirecting to the class above based a user input through a form.

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["form"] = SearchForm()

        return context
```

I think the form works completely fine, why the get_context_data does not take in any information baffles me, and I seek alternative ways to render the context based on my results from get. Any guidance on why this does not work and how to go about doing this will be great.

Thanks all

Comment: The `TemplateView.get` method will normally call `get_context_data`, but you've replaced it with a method that calls `render` straight away. It's normally a bad idea to override `get` and `post` on generic class based views for this reason -- its easy to break functionality like this, or you end up having to duplicate code.

Comment: And in any case, I can't see why you're bothering to put the data into the session. Your `get_context_data` method can access it directly from `self.request.GET`. The session is for passing data between views, not between different methods in the same view.

Comment: Thanks@Alasdair I think instead of overriding the get method, what can happen is to add a form class to the previous class. So that it will take in the searchform. and when the html action pushes it to the new url, retrieve the get parameter in the new templateview. I was trying to do that because my homeview is supposed to be clean with no forms and I wanted to keep it that way.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, I understand what you mean, so passing data in between methods, I shouldnt be using sessions, I should be using self.function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering the form using context["form"] = SearchForm(), include a formclass in the first templateview to render the form for the user.

```
class HomeView(TemplateView, FormView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    title = 'Your Dashboard'
    form_class = SearchForm
```

on the second templateview, do a self.request.GET to collect the user input inside get_context_data method.

```
 class PollSearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'polls/polls_search.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PollSearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print self.request.GET
        return context
```

This will enable the get_context_data to get the user input.